# How to convert keys of dictionary into list of values of dictionary in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to convert dictionary into a list of dictionary if the values are same. I have a sample data below:

```
my_dict={'Book 1':'Martha','Book 2':'Randy','Book 5':'Martha'}
```

Now I want to convert the above dictionary into the following output:

```
my_dict={'Randy':['Book 2'],'Martha':['Book 1','Book 5']}
```

How do I do this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help u:

```
my_dict={'Book 1':'Martha','Book 2':'Randy','Book 5':'Martha'}

final_dict = {}

for key in my_dict.keys():
    final_dict.setdefault(my_dict[key],[]).append(key)
    
print(final_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'Martha': ['Book 1', 'Book 5'], 'Randy': ['Book 2']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `collections.defaultdict` to group the keys by values:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict={'Book 1':'Martha','Book 2':'Randy','Book 5':'Martha'}

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    d[v].append(k)

print(d)
```

Output:

```py
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Martha': ['Book 1', 'Book 5'], 'Randy': ['Book 2']})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) function that is available. The code is as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict={'Book 1':'Martha','Book 2':'Randy','Book 5':'Martha'}
new_dict = defaultdict(list)
for i in my_dict:
    new_dict[my_dict[i]].append(i)

new_dict = dict(new_dict)
print(new_dict)
```